# Implementing vertical UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

After 2 days behind the implementation of a UIScrollView, I give up to do it by myself, despite It should be simple but I am not able to make it.

I need a vertical scrollview with Autolayout (I have 2 backgrounds images that need to scale), I have Xcode 7.2, iOs deployment target 9.0 and I am using the storyboard

The scrollview is a "new account" form with a lot of content, So it can have a fixed height

I tried lots of options but no one of them work, at the momment I have a scrollview with a "content view" with all of the components.

Problems:
1.- How can I put more content in the scrollview? If I try to put more compoments(more than the height of ViewControler), it automatically moves my components to be inside the ViewController rectangle

2.- How I can make it scrollable? If I pin the content view to the top, bottom, left, right and make it with fixed height (like 1000) it doesn't scroll

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: from my experience, if you want to use scrollview instead of tableview. It is much easier to do it programmatically, i.e. create view with frame, add it as subview to the scrollview and set the scrollview content size.

Comment: but It will be a pain in the ass add all the components programmatically!

Comment: if the view is complex, you can still create it in storyboard and then connected to your class. And then add it as subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollview will scroll until the end of last UI object. But this is not the default behaviour of the scrollview. You should explicitly set the `contentSize` on your scrollview. Check below example.

```
-(void)addImage {
  int count = 20;
  UIScrollView * scView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
  scView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, 60);
  UIButton * btn;
  UIImageView * imgV;
  float imgWidth = 44;
 for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
   imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   imgV.frame = CGRectMake(i*imgWidth, 0, imgWidth, 44);
   imgV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gitar"];
   [scView addSubview:imgV];
 }
[scView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imgWidth*count, 50)];
[scView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:scView];
}
```

What the above method does is, it will add 20 images in scrollview and at the end after adding all the images to scrollview in `for` loop I set `contentSize` to Scrollview. This step makes my scrollview to scroll until the content available. My example showing for Horizontal scroll, you have to change this behaviour to vertical scroll.

Comment: but this scrollview wont center by X in parent right? it will just put on 30units  on the X axis

Comment: I just showed you a example here. You create a scrollview as per your requirement. And also in my method for loop I'm increasing the 'x' origin, thats why it is a horizontal scrollview. You should increase 'y' origin to make it a vertical scrollview. At the end of my method while setting contentSize, I'm increasing width value 'imgWidth*count', you should increase height value i.e in place of '50' you should specify height value.